# Newly created users cannot create queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an intial setup of RabbitMQ and I've created a user 'user1' with a password. I've created a vhost called 'vhost1' and given the 'user1' user *. *. *. permissions to the vhost. When trying to run the rabbitmq command

This user was created using the Chef recipe for rabbitmq.

> rabbitmqadmin.py --vhost=vhost1 -u user1 -p password declare queue name=/queue1 durable=true"

I get the following response:

```
*** Access refused: /api/queues/%2Fvhost1/queue1
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I can't seem to create queues at all with a new user no matter how that user gets created. If I give the "guest" user permissions to the vhost, the guest user can create the queue, but with the same permissions, it doesn't work for my new users. I also can't log into the management console with either of the new users.

Comment: Can you post how you are creating the user? Are you using defintions.json?

Answer (score 7):

I could not create a queue because I didn't tag the new user with the "administrator" tag, which is necessary apparently for the creation of queues among other things. Although my user was created using a Chef recipe, one would run into this problem creating the user with rabbitmqadmin or the management console if the created user was not given the administrator tag after creation.

Comment: This is the same problem I had, thanks for answering.